# How does one use the jquery-plugin "inline form validation engine" with radio buttons (one option required)?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, jquery-plugins, knockout.js, jquery-validation-engine

Right now I am working on a project that uses the "Inline Form Validation Engine 2.6.2", jQuery plugin by C.Dugas and O.Refalo (because many people here know it best). On top of that we are reworking many pages to use knockout.js.

*Now to my problem:*
My usecases determine that the selection of an option is required and it is also required that the user **explicitly** chooses the option - especially the 'I don't have a job' one - wherefore my suggestion of using that option as a default option was not acceptable.

From what I found via the original documentation of the given jquery-plugin I concluded that my inputs needed the attributes **type="radio"** and **data_validation_engine="validate[required] group"**.

Following that information I ended up with this code to create my radiobuttons:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: radioButtonOptions.Company, visible: true" style="">
            <div>
                <input type="radio" data_validation_engine="validate[required] radio" name="Company" data-bind="value: Value, checked: $root.model.Company, attr: { id: 'Company'+Value() }" data-errormessage-value-missing="Please choose your employer." data-prompt-target="ym-message-Company" value="0" id="Company0">
                <label data-bind="attr: { for: 'Company'+Value() }, text:Text" for="Company0">I don't have a job!</label>
            </div>

            <div>
                <input type="radio" data_validation_engine="validate[required] radio" name="Company" data-bind="value: Value, checked: $root.model.Company, attr: { id: 'Company'+Value() }" data-errormessage-value-missing="Please choose your employer." data-prompt-target="ym-message-Company" value="1" id="Company1">
                <label data-bind="attr: { for: 'Company'+Value() }, text:Text" for="Company1">Softdrink Company</label>
            </div>

            <div>
                <input type="radio" data_validation_engine="validate[required] radio" name="Company" data-bind="value: Value, checked: $root.model.Company, attr: { id: 'Company'+Value() }" data-errormessage-value-missing="Please choose your employer." data-prompt-target="ym-message-Company" value="2" id="Company2">
                <label data-bind="attr: { for: 'Company'+Value() }, text:Text" for="Company2">Food Company</label>
            </div>
        </div>
```

So that will end up in 3 nicely labelled and unselected RadioButtons.

My submit button will then check the forms validity prior to sending the post:

```
$("#submitButton").click(function (event) {
    if (!$('#inputForm').validationEngine('validate'))
        return false;
    // submit per ajax ...
});
```

and thereby prevent submitting if the validation fails.

This works properly for any "validate[required]"-rule I have set on select-lists and textboxes and even through a small extension for my DateTime Editor-Template that splits the date in 3 different inputs and reassembles it onchange in a fourth hidden field.

But for some reason - which I fail to see -  it will not work with my radiobutton lists.

Did anyone encounter a similar problem with this plugin and was able to solve it or does anyone by chance have a good idea how to try and find the problem... I have to admit right now I feel a little stuck

Thx in advance for any help and/or suggestions that will lead to a solution!

Comment: what's is the `data_validation_engine` ? i think the validation rules should add to `class` only. can you give the documentation you checked?

Comment: Oh I have to admit, I only checked the "..." syntax in the online documentation of the plugins website. Didnt think that data_validation_engine might be wrong. I read it in the js-files they gave me and on the first glance that looked valid as it checks for data_validation_engine OR class attribute containing the rule... well if data_validation_engine is not part of the original implementation then maybe someone modified it and oversaw something, will try the whole thing with class now and respond asap

Comment: got it. i've found something strange in your code and will try to give a solution. but i am not familiar with your framework like `knockout.js`, so it's just a pure validationEngine solution and maybe you still need to try out yourself.

Comment: OMG... THANKS leonhart! Well you actually can use "data-validation-engine" or "class" both attributes will be checked (just had a look at the plugins github code) the problem here was that for some reason my code generated "data_validation_engine" (with understores instead of dashes). Just fixed that and tadaa! it works!

Comment: so i don't need to give any solution now, glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I had a typo in my code generation. My generator wrote "data_validation_engine" instead of "data-validation-engine". Sadly, I just didn't see the difference between my code and the example code of the plugins official documentation page. But - triggered on leonhart's comment - having a closer look into the engines source code I finally realized the typo.
Thanks again Leonhart!